# Finding mapping from set of start nodes to set of destination nodes in a grid

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, breadth-first-search

We are given a N x M size grid. Each cell represents height of cell.
You can travel to north/south/east/west of a cell if the neighbouring cell has a lower height.

All cells in first row are considered as set of start nodes.
All cells in last row are considered as set of destination nodes.

Find a binary matrix of size M x M where Matrix[i][j] = 1 iff I can start at cell (0, i) and reach to cell (N-1, j).

Here N, M <= 2000 and height of each cell is less than 10^9.

---

I have tried several approaches.
***Observation***: This grid is actually a DAG (Directed Acyclic Graph).

**Approach #1**: Do DFS from each cell in first row and find out list of cells you can reach at last row. This could take in worst case O(NxMxM) which is expensive.

**Approach #2**: Do DFS from each cell in first row and find out list of cells you can reach at last row, but do not re-do DFS for a cell if you have visited. Instead at each cell memorize the visitable cells in last row. Problem in this approach is it takes too much space: O(NxMxM).

Third idea is to think DSU (Disjoint Set Union) but it doesn't seem to be working. Spent couple of days thinking over this problem but cannot find a valid solution. TIA.

Comment: You could prune the problem somewhat by realizing that a cell in the first row can only reach cells in the last row that are no more than the first row cell height minus the number of rows ( because to reach a higher cell it has to climb somewhere and that is forbidden )  So the N*M*M worst cases you suggest will never be reached unless every cell in every row is lower than the three cells above it in the previous row.

Comment: @ravenspoint Makes sense, but N*M*M is too slow.

Answer (score 1):

The grid is a DAG, but it also has the special property that no edges cross.

Let's classify each source vertex as either "live", if you can start there and reach *some* vertex in the last row, or "dead" if you cannot.  It's not hard to classify the source vertices in O(NM) time.

Now we need only consider live sources.  Since no edges can cross, for any vertex v, the live sources that can reach it must be *contiguous*.  If there are sources a and b can reach v, then there is no way that a source between a and b could reach the end without joining a path that can reach v.

So, for each vertex, the sources that can reach it can be expressed as a *range* of sources (just 2 numbers), instead of a *subset*, which would be much bigger and more difficult to calculate.

If you process all of the vertices in order of descending height, then you can calculate the source range for each vertex from the source ranges of its neighbors in constant time.  Each vertex can only be reached from its higher neighbors, and they will have been already calculated by the time you get to the vertex.  Of course you must also consider that each source vertex is reachable from itself.

The time required for this algorithm is dominated by the sorting of vertices by height, and takes O(NM log NM) time.

Comment: "no edges cross"  Consider the case where the height of every call in row r is 2 and every call in row r+1 is 1.  Each cell in row r can reach three cells in row r+1.  The connections from a row r cells CROSS the connections from the adjacent row r cells.

Comment: @ravenspoint question says you can go N/S/W/E

Comment: The point is that your statement that edges cannot cross is untrue.

Comment: @ravenspoint  No, the statement is correct, because paths can't move diagonally.  Each cell in row r can directly connect to only one cell in row r+1